# how do I cycle through background images by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to preview some backgrounds by using a button to cycle through them, just not very good at the js. I have them named "1"-"13". I wanted to step through them. When I get to "13" I want it to set it back to "1" when "next" is clicked and when "prev" is clicked when it gets to "1" to set it to "13". This is what I've tried but I know my syntax is wrong for the js.

HTML

```
<button id="n" class="b">NEXT</button>
<button id="p" class="b">PREV</button>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background:black;
}

.b {
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var i = 1;

$("#n").click(function() {
    alert(i);
    i++;
    $('body').css("background-image",  "url(../images/bg/ " + i + " .png)");
       if (i===14){i=1;};
 });

$("#p").click(function() {
    alert(i);
    i--;
    $('body').css("background-image",  "url(../images/bg/ " + i + " .png)");
        if (i===0){i=13;};
});
});
```

Still working on it but some help would be nice getting it done faster.
http://jsfiddle.net/80nz56wy/ I guess a jsfiddle won't help much if I'm using local content.

Comment: `"bg" + "i++" + ".png"` SERIOUSLY?

Comment: Hey, I just started learning this stuff, no need to be so harsh. If I knew what I was doing I wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's stepping through the variable just fine, I must have some code off a little, still trying to find what might be wrong.

Comment: Updated my js above, still working on it.

Comment: @user3888510 check this http://jsfiddle.net/80nz56wy/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also try this. Here conditions are written before setting CSS, which will check first and then assign the image path.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;

    $("#n").click(function() {
        i++;
        if (i > 13){ i = 1; };
        $('body').css('background-image',  'url(images/bg/' + i + '.png)');
       //if (i === 13){ i = 1; };
    });

    $("#p").click(function() {
        i--;
        if (i <= 0) { i = 13; };
        $('body').css('background-image',  'url(images/bg/' + i + '.png)');
        //if (i === 1) { i = 13; };
    });
});
```

Other wise you may get wrong image paths, something like:

```
images/bg/0.png
```

or

```
images/bg/-1.png
```

Comment: I was having some image path issues and that helped to clear them up and makes more sense, thanks. Why does it matter if the if statement comes before the css change, there aren't any other changes happening. Also, the ../ was incorrect and does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Change Your javascript coding as below..

```
var i = 1;

    $("#n").click(function() {
        $('body').css("background-image", "bg" + i +".png");
    i=i+1;
    if (i==13){i=1};
    });


    $("#p").click(function() {
            $('body').css("background-image", "bg" + i +".png");
    i=i-1;
    if (i==1){i=13};
    });
```

Comment: Not quite working, just remembered that my images are in images/bg  how would this line go  $('body').css("background-image", "url("../images/bg/" + "bg" + i + ".png")";

Comment: Thanks for the help, not quite working yet, feels so close. On the second line where the $('body') is it says it's expecting an ident but found a .

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, not sure what I changed the 20 times I edited the same line over and over but I must have gone full retard earlier.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var i = 0;

    $("#n").click(function() {
        i++;
        if ( i > 13 ){ i = 1; };
        $('body').css('background-image',  'url(images/bg/' + i + '.png)');   
    });

    $("#p").click(function() {
        i--;
        if ( i <= 0 ){ i = 13; };
        $('body').css('background-image',  'url(images/bg/' + i + '.png)');    
    });
});
```